# Проверка "кратности" чисел python

Tags: python

Как можно реализовать функцию, проверяющую кратность числа?
Например: если а > 3000 и оно равно 3500, или 4000, или 4500, или 5000 и т.д., то есть через каждые 500, то выводится, например +
Если a > 3000 и оно равно любым другим числам: 3200, 3750, 4700 и т.д., то выводился -.

Comment: через проверку остатка от деления на 500 через `%`. Потратьте 15 минут и осильте хотя бы первые 5 страниц начального курса по питону

Comment: Вроде пробовал через %, но не получалось. А щас получилось. Спасибо)

Comment: Вот что пендаль животворящий делает!